# Copy from one into another file

Tags: c, file, copy

Hi this is a very simple little program, but it doeasnt work for me :(
There is just nothing happening after i type in two names of .txt files.
It does not even return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char datei1[100], datei2[100];
    char ch;

    gets(datei1);
    f1=fopen(datei1, "r");
    if(f1==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open %s", datei1); 
        return 1;
    }
    gets(datei2);
    f2=fopen(datei2, "a");
    if(f2==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open %s", datei2); 
        return 1;
    }

    while((ch=getch(f1))!=EOF){
        putch(ch,f2);
    }

    printf("Complete");
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `char ch;` to `int ch;`.

Comment: Never use `gets()`. Use `fgets(datei1, sizeof datei1, stdin);` as a drop-in replacement. Much safer.

Comment: Also change `putch(ch, f2);` to `fputc(ch, f2);`

Comment: You are using both obsolete and non-standard functions. Wherever you are leaning C from, it is teaching you to use things that shouldn't be used. Consider leaning from another source instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change `getch` to `fgetc`. `getch` is a VisualC function to read from keyboard.